# Binary outcome - what test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, pre-post-comparison

I am doing a study where I assess the knowledge of the same group of people before and after a teaching session.
The question ask if the risk of developing cancer is higher or lower in the adult population compared to the paediatric population after being exposed to a particular medicine.

The answer is binary:

```
0 = risk is higher in the adult population

1 = risk is higher in the paediatric population
```

Example:

```
Pre [0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0]

Post [1, 0, 1 ,1 ,0 ,0]
```

(Same people but fewer people answered the post test than pre-test)

I repeat this question before and after the teaching session. I am unsure which statistical test to use to see if there is a significant difference between the two groups. Please can someone help me identify an appropriate test for this?

Comment: Do you ask multiple questions? The same questions before and after?

Comment: The other questions use continuous data but all questions are identical before and after. Hence I am only asking about a test for this data as it is binary

Comment: You seem to have a different number of respondents pre- and post-.  Were they the same people?

Comment: Yes - but unfortunatley I couldn't get all people who answered the initial test to answer the repeat test.

Comment: Have you considered McNemar's test?

Comment: Thank you. I am not a statistian by training but that seems appropriate. I appreciate it

Comment: But you **do** know the pairing between pre and post?

Comment: How so? I have no way of pairing up the answers. I didn't take personal information